# How to reduce the loading time to setvalue to the farpoint in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, oracle

I have a problem to set vaule in farpoint through the javascript
There was taken lot of loading time to set the value in farpoint

```
if (row != 0) {

        if (ss.GetValue(row, col) != "") {
            sTrips = parseFloat(ss.GetValue(row, col));   
        }
        if (ss.GetValue(0, col) != "") {
            sWrkDays = parseFloat(ss.GetValue(0, col));      
        }
        for (var i = 1; i < ssDet.GetRowCount(); i++) {

                if (ssDet.GetValue(i, 7) != "") { 
                    sMaxCapacity = parseFloat(ssDet.GetValue(i, 7));
                    sVal = 0;
                    sVal = sMaxCapacity * sTrips * sWrkDays;
                    var cell = ssDet.GetCellByRowCol(i, col + 5); 
                    cell.removeAttribute("fpcelltype");

                    ssDet.SetValue(i, col + 5, sVal);
                    cell.setAttribute("FpCellType", "readonly");
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can optimize some of your code. instead of calling the same method "ss.GetValue(row, col)" twice you can assigned value in some variable and do operation on that.

Answer (score 0):

try below optimized code for better result

```
if (row != 0) {
        var sTripsVal = ss.GetValue(row, col);
        var workingDays = ss.GetValue(0, col);

        if (sTripsVal != "") {
            sTrips = parseFloat(sTripsVal);   
        }
        if (workingDays  != "") {
            sWrkDays = parseFloat(workingDays);      
        }

        for (var i = 1; i < ssDet.GetRowCount(); i++) 
        {
                var MaxCapacity = ssDet.GetValue(i, 7);
                if (MaxCapacity != "") 
                { 
                    sMaxCapacity = parseFloat(MaxCapacity);
                    sVal = 0;
                    sVal = sMaxCapacity * sTrips * sWrkDays;
                    var cell = ssDet.GetCellByRowCol(i, col + 5); 
                    cell.removeAttribute("fpcelltype");

                    ssDet.SetValue(i, col + 5, sVal);
                    cell.setAttribute("FpCellType", "readonly");
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for Helping, But the same problem is still contain.  there was 171 data contain to fill the farpoint. if the 170 data contain thae resson to the loading time or my coding is mistake. How to solve this Challange

Comment: are you able to do this from C# or from procedure?

Comment: if it solve any way to javascript. is that better for me , else there is lot of changes me in C#. becuose The calculations and etc... alathings now happen in the javascript

Comment: any one know how to reduce the loading time here. it is 7sec load time. and need to add some of calcualation here also, like sum = parseFloat(sum) + sVal;         anyone know how to solve this